# Tk Frame loses its size when creating a child Label

Tags: tkinter, tk-toolkit, ttk

Here's the relevant piece of code

```
self.testFrame = ttk.LabelFrame(self, height = 300, width = 300)
self.anotherString = ttk.Label(self.testFrame, text="lol")
self.testFrame.grid(column = 0, row = 2)
self.testFrame.pack_propagate(0)
self.anotherString.grid(column = 0, row =0)
```

A lot of the answers on here told me to use pack_propagate(0), but that doesn't seem to help. The result is a small LabelFrame with the word lol in it, but it should be bigger. Why is it losing its 300x300 size?

Comment: Experience has taught me that turning geometry propagation off is rarely the right thing to do. Create your interior widgets with appropriate sizes and let Tkinter figure out the size of the frames. This is especially true if your program will run on more than just your own system -- different machines have different fonts and resolutions, and while 300x300 might look good for you, it might not look good for others.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You use `grid()` so you need `grid_propagate(0)`

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

root = tk.Tk()

testFrame = ttk.LabelFrame(root, height=300, width=300)
testFrame.grid(column=0, row=2)

anotherString = ttk.Label(testFrame, text="lol")
anotherString.grid(column=0, row=0)

#testFrame.pack_propagate(0)
testFrame.grid_propagate(0)

root.mainloop()
```